# Bootstrap Collapse Panels not pushing the page footer down when expanding

Tags: html, css

On this page: https://www.ppai.org/members/certification/certification-programs/ we have added bootstrap accordion functionality to our panels.

The issue is that the content window does not expand when the accordions open, so at the bottom of the page, you end up with content hidden behind the footer.

I understand positioning and I'm sure that either a height is being set on one of the containers or something is getting changed to a fixed position. I've just pulled out most of the hair I have left trying to find which container is the culprit.

I was hoping to find a wizard here that could help me spot the offender.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Trent! Welcome to SO, It would be great for everyone here if you can post your code so we have something to check.

Comment: @Paolo, I would love to, but this is a huge page on our production web site. It would be way too much code to post and to pare it down would negate the problem.

Comment: Oh my bad @Trent Grandey so the link was your website.